# MySQL AES_DECRYPT password does not match plain one

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this will banal but I cannot figure out!

I have a user table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_users (
  usr_id        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  usr_name      VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  usr_surname   VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  usr_pwd       BLOB NOT NULL ,
  usr_level     INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY ( usr_id )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

With one record:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_users ( usr_id, usr_name, usr_pwd, usr_level )
VALUES (NULL, 'SU', AES_ENCRYPT('SU', SHA2('MyPwd', 512)), 2);
```

Now, If I run this query (in phpMyAdmin) I get my record:

```
SELECT usr_id, usr_name, usr_surname, usr_level, 
       AES_DECRYPT(usr_pwd, SHA2('MyPwd', 512)) as usr_pwd
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE usr_name='SU';
```

But if I add the password check I get an empty resultset:

```
SELECT usr_id, usr_name, usr_surname, usr_level, 
       AES_DECRYPT(usr_pwd, SHA2('MyPwd', 512)) as usr_pwd
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE usr_name='SU' and usr_pwd='SU';
```

Where I wrong?

Comment: You're aliasing  the column you're trying to access as the column name, I don't know if that's the problem, but it's confusing to read / understand.

Comment: @Matthew in a first time I have suppose the same thing but changing the alias to another name does not have any effect.

Comment: I will recommend to encrypt the input password.

Comment: Ok but, apart the best practice, why the SQL query does not work?